# I got Bad Request (400) when I'm redirected to an url using HttpWebRequest C#

Tags: c#

I used HttpWebRequest to upload a file:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = contentType;
request.UserAgent = userAgent;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.ContentLength = formData.Length;
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}

// construct boundary etc...

var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

In the last line I got exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I inspected the `request` variable and I saw that `Exception.Response.ResponseUri` property is a redirected url (after successful upload) which looks like:

```
https://fakeurl.com/add.php?result[]=success&name[]=data_file[]
```

Why ?

How to avoid that exception which say is bad request since the response is a success one ?

I checked with fiddler and I got 200 as status code.

Comment: Is your `formData.Length` correct?

Comment: What does mean if is correct ? It more than 0 for sure...

Comment: Can you provide us with the actual url you are trying to reach?